# Uncaught Error - TypeError: data.forEach is not a function (csv file)

Tags: html, d3.js

I am having issues with this function.

```
d3.csv("a1-burtin.csv", function(error, data) { 
  var antibiotics = ["Penicilin", "Streptomycin", "Neomycin"]; 
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.antibiotics = antibiotics.map(function(name) {
      return {name: name, value: +d[name], gs: d['Gram Staining']}; 
    });
  });
});
```

The issue is:

> Uncaught Error - TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

When I console log the data, it shows 0. Is it supposed to show 0 or the content of the csv file?

Comment: What's the D3 version?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado d3 version i am using is v5.9.1